# Python Hyperlinks function

Tags: python, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a function in python which reads an html and then takes out only the hyperlink and the theme of the hyperlink..The html page is specific and the function is only for this page..So as i'm a really amateur in python learning i thought something like this..

```
def fun("string","start of hyper","end of hyper")
```

.And when i call this function,i'll read the html file,and pop up only the parts which have tha classic html words for start and finish hyperlinks `<a,</a>` .Also i must not use any modules like beautiful soup for this function!!Thanks for any response

Answer (score 2):

This might be the **complete solution** as you are looking for.

> This code is from the [udacity computer science course](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101) (CS101)

It uses simulated webpages using method `get_page(url):`

> **Run in your computer once and read the code**

It also try to **remove duplicate urls**

```
def get_page(url):
    # This is a simulated get_page procedure so that you can test your
    # code on two pages "http://xkcd.com/353" and "http://xkcd.com/554".
    # A procedure which actually grabs a page from the web will be 
    # introduced in unit 4.
    try:
        if url == "http://xkcd.com/353":
            return  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><?xml-stylesheet href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/c40a9f8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>xkcd: Python</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/c40a9f8.css" media="screen" title="Default" /> <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/ecbbecc.css" media="screen" title="Default" /><![endif]--> <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" href="/atom.xml" /> <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="/rss.xml" /> <link rel="icon" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/919f273.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/919f273.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> </head> <body> <div id="container"> <div id="topContainer"> <div id="topLeft" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s">\t<ul> <li><a href="http://xkcd.com/554"">Archive</a><br /></li>\t <li><a href="http://blag.xkcd.com/">News/Blag</a><br /></li> <li><a href="http://store.xkcd.com/">Store</a><br /></li> <li><a href="/about/">About</a><br /></li> <li><a href="http://forums.xkcd.com/">Forums</a><br /></li> </ul> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> <div id="topRight" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s"> <div id="topRightContainer"> <div id="logo"> <a href="/"><img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/9be30a7.png" alt="xkcd.com logo" height="83" width="185"/></a> <h2><br />A webcomic of romance,<br/> sarcasm, math, and language.</h2> <div class="clearleft"></div> <br />XKCD updates every Monday, Wednesday, and Friday. </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> </div> <div id="contentContainer"> <div id="middleContent" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s"><h1>Python</h1><br/><br /><div class="menuCont"> <ul> <li><a href="/1/">|&lt;</a></li> <li><a href="/352/" accesskey="p">&lt; Prev</a></li> <li><a href="http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/" id="rnd_btn_t">Random</a></li> <li><a href="/354/" accesskey="n">Next &gt;</a></li> <li><a href="/">&gt;|</a></li> </ul></div><br/><br/><img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python.png" title="I wrote 20 short programs in Python yesterday. It was wonderful. Perl, Im leaving you." alt="Python" /><br/><br/><div class="menuCont"> <ul> <li><a href="/1/">|&lt;</a></li> <li><a href="/352/" accesskey="p">&lt; Prev</a></li> <li><a href="http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/" id="rnd_btn_b">Random</a></li> <li><a href="/354/" accesskey="n">Next &gt;</a></li> <li><a href="/">&gt;|</a></li> </ul></div><h3>Permanent link to this comic: http://xkcd.com/353/</h3><h3>Image URL (for hotlinking/embedding): http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python.png</h3><div id="transcript" style="display: none">[[ Guy 1 is talking to Guy 2, who is floating in the sky ]]Guy 1: You39;re flying! How?Guy 2: Python!Guy 2: I learned it last night! Everything is so simple!Guy 2: Hello world is just 39;print &quot;Hello, World!&quot; 39;Guy 1: I dunno... Dynamic typing? Whitespace?Guy 2: Come join us! Programming is fun again! It39;s a whole new world up here!Guy 1: But how are you flying?Guy 2: I just typed 39;import antigravity39;Guy 1: That39;s it?Guy 2: ...I also sampled everything in the medicine cabinet for comparison.Guy 2: But i think this is the python.{{ I wrote 20 short programs in Python yesterday. It was wonderful. Perl, I39;m leaving you. }}</div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> <div id="middleFooter" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s"> <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/a899e84.jpg" width="520" height="100" alt="Selected Comics" usemap=" comicmap" /> <map name="comicmap"> <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="/150/" alt="Grownups" /> <area shape="rect" coords="104,0,204,100" href="/730/" alt="Circuit Diagram" /> <area shape="rect" coords="208,0,308,100" href="/162/" alt="Angular Momentum" /> <area shape="rect" coords="312,0,412,100" href="/688/" alt="Self-Description" /> <area shape="rect" coords="416,0,520,100" href="/556/" alt="Alternative Energy Revolution" /> </map><br/><br />Search comic titles and transcripts:<br /><script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script type="text/javascript"> google.load(\"search\", \"1\"); google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { google.search.CustomSearchControl.attachAutoCompletion( \"012652707207066138651:zudjtuwe28q\", document.getElementById(\"q\"), \"cse-search-box\"); });</script><form action="//www.google.com/cse" id="cse-search-box"> <div> <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="012652707207066138651:zudjtuwe28q" /> <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" /> <input type="text" name="q" id="q" autocomplete="off" size="31" /> <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" /> </div></form><script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&lang=en"></script><a href="/rss.xml">RSS Feed</a> - <a href="/atom.xml">Atom Feed</a><br /> <br/> <div id="comicLinks"> Comics I enjoy:<br/> <a href="http://www.qwantz.com">Dinosaur Comics</a>, <a href="http://www.asofterworld.com">A Softer World</a>, <a href="http://pbfcomics.com/">Perry Bible Fellowship</a>, <a href="http://www.boltcity.com/copper/">Copper</a>, <a href="http://questionablecontent.net/">Questionable Content</a>, <a href="http://achewood.com/">Achewood</a>, <a href="http://wondermark.com/">Wondermark</a>, <a href="http://thisisindexed.com/">Indexed</a>, <a href="http://www.buttercupfestival.com/buttercupfestival.htm">Buttercup Festival</a> </div> <br/> Warning: this comic occasionally contains strong language (which may be unsuitable for children), unusual humor (which may be unsuitable for adults), and advanced mathematics (which may be unsuitable for liberal-arts majors).<br/> <br/> <h4>We did not invent the algorithm. The algorithm consistently finds Jesus. The algorithm killed Jeeves. <br />The algorithm is banned in China. The algorithm is from Jersey. The algorithm constantly finds Jesus.<br />This is not the algorithm. This is close.</h4><br/> <div class="line"></div> <br/> <div id="licenseText"> <!-- <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border:none" src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/static/somerights20.png" /></a><br/> --> This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 2.5 License</a>.<!-- <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns "><Work rdf:about=""><dc:creator>Randall Munroe</dc:creator><dcterms:rightsHolder>Randall Munroe</dcterms:rightsHolder><dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:source rdf:resource="http://www.xkcd.com/"/><license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/" /></Work><License rdf:about="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/"><permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Reproduction" /><permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Distribution" /><requires rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Notice" /><requires rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Attribution" /><prohibits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/CommercialUse" /><permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/DerivativeWorks" /></License></rdf:RDF> --> <br/> This means you\"re free to copy and share these comics (but not to sell them). <a href="/license.html">More details</a>.<br/> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> </div> </div> </body></html> '
        elif url == "http://xkcd.com/554":
            return  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <?xml-stylesheet href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/c40a9f8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" ?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>xkcd: Not Enough Work</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/c40a9f8.css" media="screen" title="Default" /> <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/ecbbecc.css" media="screen" title="Default" /><![endif]--> <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" href="/atom.xml" /> <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="/rss.xml" /> <link rel="icon" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/919f273.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/919f273.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> </head> <body> <div id="container"> <div id="topContainer"> <div id="topLeft" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s"> <ul> <li><a href="/archive/">Archive</a><br /></li> <li><a href="http://blag.xkcd.com/">News/Blag</a><br /></li> <li><a href="http://store.xkcd.com/">Store</a><br /></li> <li><a href="/about/">About</a><br /></li> <li><a href="http://forums.xkcd.com/">Forums</a><br /></li> </ul> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> <div id="topRight" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s"> <div id="topRightContainer"> <div id="logo"> <a href="/"><img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/9be30a7.png" alt="xkcd.com logo" height="83" width="185"/></a> <h2><br />A webcomic of romance,<br/> sarcasm, math, and language.</h2> <div class="clearleft"></div> XKCD updates every Monday, Wednesday, and Friday. <br /> Blag: Remember geohashing? <a href="http://blog.xkcd.com/2012/02/27/geohashing-2/">Something pretty cool</a> happened Sunday. </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> </div> <div id="contentContainer"> <div id="middleContent" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s"> <h1>Not Enough Work</h1><br/> <br /> <div class="menuCont"> <ul> <li><a href="/1/">|&lt;</a></li> <li><a href="/553/" accesskey="p">&lt; Prev</a></li> <li><a href="http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/" id="rnd_btn_t">Random</a></li> <li><a href="/555/" accesskey="n">Next &gt;</a></li> <li><a href="/">&gt;|</a></li> </ul> </div> <br/> <br/> <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/not_enough_work.png" title="It39;s even harder if you39;re an asshole who pronounces &lt;&gt; brackets." alt="Not Enough Work" /><br/> <br/> <div class="menuCont"> <ul> <li><a href="/1/">|&lt;</a></li> <li><a href="/553/" accesskey="p">&lt; Prev</a></li> <li><a href="http://dynamic.xkcd.com/random/comic/" id="rnd_btn_b">Random</a></li> <li><a href="/555/" accesskey="n">Next &gt;</a></li> <li><a href="/">&gt;|</a></li> </ul> </div> <h3>Permanent link to this comic: http://xkcd.com/554/</h3> <h3>Image URL (for hotlinking/embedding): http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/not_enough_work.png</h3> <div id="transcript" style="display: none">Narration: Signs your coders don39;t have enough work to do: [[A man sitting at his workstation; a female co-worker behind him]] Man: I39;m almost up to my old typing speed in dvorak [[Two men standing by a server rack]] Man  1: Our servers now support gopher. Man  1: Just in case. [[A woman standing near her workstation speaking to a male co-worker]] Woman: Our pages are now HTML, XHTML-STRICT, and haiku-compliant Man: Haiku? Woman: &lt;div class=&quot;main&quot;&gt; Woman: &lt;span id=&quot;marquee&quot;&gt; Woman: Blog!&lt; span&gt;&lt; div&gt; [[A woman sitting at her workstation]] Woman: Hey! Have you guys seen this webcomic? {{title text: It39;s even harder if you39;re an asshole who pronounces &lt;&gt; brackets.}}</div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> <div id="middleFooter" class="dialog"> <div class="hd"><div class="c"></div></div> <div class="bd"> <div class="c"> <div class="s"> <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/s/a899e84.jpg" width="520" height="100" alt="Selected Comics" usemap=" comicmap" /> <map name="comicmap"> <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="/150/" alt="Grownups" /> <area shape="rect" coords="104,0,204,100" href="/730/" alt="Circuit Diagram" /> <area shape="rect" coords="208,0,308,100" href="/162/" alt="Angular Momentum" /> <area shape="rect" coords="312,0,412,100" href="/688/" alt="Self-Description" /> <area shape="rect" coords="416,0,520,100" href="/556/" alt="Alternative Energy Revolution" /> </map><br/><br /> Search comic titles and transcripts:<br /> <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> google.load("search", "1"); google.search.CustomSearchControl.attachAutoCompletion( "012652707207066138651:zudjtuwe28q", document.getElementById("q"), "cse-search-box"); }); </script> <form action="//www.google.com/cse" id="cse-search-box"> <div> <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="012652707207066138651:zudjtuwe28q" /> <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" /> <input type="text" name="q" id="q" autocomplete="off" size="31" /> <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" /> </div> </form> <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&lang=en"></script> <a href="/rss.xml">RSS Feed</a> - <a href="/atom.xml">Atom Feed</a> <br /> <br/> <div id="comicLinks"> Comics I enjoy:<br/> <a href="http://threewordphrase.com/">Three Word Phrase</a>, <a href="http://oglaf.com/">Oglaf</a> (nsfw), <a href="http://www.smbc-comics.com/">SMBC</a>, <a href="http://www.qwantz.com">Dinosaur Comics</a>, <a href="http://www.asofterworld.com">A Softer World</a>, <a href="http://buttersafe.com/">Buttersafe</a>, <a href="http://pbfcomics.com/">Perry Bible Fellowship</a>, <a href="http://questionablecontent.net/">Questionable Content</a>, <a href="http://www.buttercupfestival.com/buttercupfestival.htm">Buttercup Festival</a> </div> <br/> Warning: this comic occasionally contains strong language (which may be unsuitable for children), unusual humor (which may be unsuitable for adults), and advanced mathematics (which may be unsuitable for liberal-arts majors).<br/> <br/> <h4>We did not invent the algorithm. The algorithm consistently finds Jesus. The algorithm killed Jeeves. <br />The algorithm is banned in China. The algorithm is from Jersey. The algorithm constantly finds Jesus.<br />This is not the algorithm. This is close.</h4><br/> <div class="line"></div> <br/> <div id="licenseText"> <!-- <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border:none" src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/static/somerights20.png" /></a><br/> --> This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 2.5 License</a>. <!-- <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns "><Work rdf:about=""><dc:creator>Randall Munroe</dc:creator><dcterms:rightsHolder>Randall Munroe</dcterms:rightsHolder><dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:source rdf:resource="http://www.xkcd.com/"/><license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/" /></Work><License rdf:about="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/"><permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Reproduction" /><permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Distribution" /><requires rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Notice" /><requires rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/Attribution" /><prohibits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/CommercialUse" /><permits rdf:resource="http://web.resource.org/cc/DerivativeWorks" /></License></rdf:RDF> --> <br/> This means you"re free to copy and share these comics (but not to sell them). <a href="/license.html">More details</a>.<br/> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="ft"><div class="c"></div></div> </div> </div> </div> </body> </html> '
    except:
        return ""
    return ""

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1: 
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

def union(p,q):
    for e in q:
        if e not in p:
            p.append(e)


def get_all_links(page):
    links = []
    while True:
        url,endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            links.append(url)
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break
    return links

def crawl_web(seed):
    tocrawl = [seed]
    crawled = []
    while tocrawl:
        page = tocrawl.pop()
        if page not in crawled:
            union(tocrawl, get_all_links(get_page(page)))
        crawled.append(page)
    return crawled

print crawl_web('http://xkcd.com/353')
```

Comment: thanx i've already tried something similar..and i'm trying now to print together the shown title of the hyperlink..somethink like www.example.com-EXAMPLE  or www.game.com-GAME

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract urls from a html file? Then this is what you need:

http://youtu.be/MagGZY7wHfU?t=1m54s

Its a great course by the way. Maybe you are interested.

Comment: Really thanx a lot!These courses are very helpful for my everyday studying in Python!!

Answer (score 0):

To parse html file you should use XML parsing library. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html